Calculate the residue of the general function $\frac{1}{z^n+1}$ at the root $e^\frac{i*\pi}{n}$
I am trying to evaluate the integral of $\frac{1}{x^n+1}, n \in (1.5, \infty)$ from $0$ to $\infty$ by using contour integration. I have found the location of the pole inside the contour I am using, which is at $e^\frac{i\pi}{n}$, and am trying to calculate the residue at that point. The issue is, I've tried to do so and check my answer against Wolfram Alpha, but it doesn't recognise that there is a pole at that point - it says the residue is $0$. Could someone help me out here?

It's best to substitute $y=x^n$ first because non-integer powers don't play nice with the concept of poles. (If $n$ is an integer, a sector contour works well without the substitution.) You can prove$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^n+1}=\frac{\pi}{n}\csc\frac{\pi}{n}$$for $n>1$.

I know, but I still would like to evaluate it in this manner. It's a good exercise.

Mathematica gives me $-\frac1n(-1)^{1/n}$.

@Ramashalanka Thank you! What about for $e^\frac{-i\pi}{n}$, that's the other root (appearing when 1<n<1.5)

$\mathrm{Res}_{z=e^{\pm i\pi/n}}(z^n+1)^{-1} = -\frac1n(-1)^{-1/n}$ (the result I gave before was another way of saying the same thing.

I now see there is a good answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/121135/7515 Actually both answers to that question are good.

@Ramashalanka For some reason, when I include this pole the resulting integral isn't true for 1<n<=1.5 - it doubles when it shouldn't. Am I missing something?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Essentially a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21928/how-to-find-int-0-infty-fracdx1x24
